# Infinitesimal generator/intensity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am trying to understand the following example, but I do not understand how they get $P(t)$. What are they doing with the diagonal matrix to get the three matrices with $e^{-t}$, $e^{-3t}$ and $e^{-4t}$ in front?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are exponentiating. Recall that $$e^x = 1 + \frac x{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ...$$
You can define the same power series for matrices. Given a square matrix $M$, you can define
$$e^M := I + \frac 1{1!}M + \frac{1}{2!}M^2 + \frac{1}{3!}M^3 + ...$$
Just as in the real case, this series always converges, and it solves similar multivariate differential equations. In particular, $\mathbf P_t = e^{t\mathbf A}$.

Since $\mathbf A= \mathbf {QDQ}^{-1}$, $$\mathbf A^n = \mathbf {QDQ}^{-1}\mathbf {QDQ}^{-1}\mathbf {QDQ}^{-1}...\mathbf {QDQ}^{-1} = \mathbf {QD}^n\mathbf Q^{-1}$$
From which it follows that $e^{t\mathbf A} = \mathbf Q\ e^{t\mathbf D}\mathbf Q^{-1}$

Now, it isn't hard to workout that if $\mathbf D = \text{diag}(d_1, ..., d_4)$ then $e^{\mathbf D} = \text{diag}(e^{d_1}, ..., e^{d_4})$.

So $$\mathbf P_t = e^{t\mathbf A} = \mathbf Q\ e^{t\mathbf D}\mathbf Q^{-1}=\mathbf Q\begin{bmatrix}e^0&0&0&0\\0&e^{-t}&0&0\\0&0&e^{-3t}&0\\0&0&0&e^{-4t}\end{bmatrix}\mathbf Q^{-1}$$
which when you expand out using the $\mathbf Q$ matrices gives the result $$\frac 1{12}\begin{bmatrix}
3+8e^{-t}+e^{-4t}&3-3e^{-4t}&3-4e^{-t}+e^{-4t}&3-4e^{-t}+e^{-4t}\\
3-3e^{-4t}&3+9e^{-4t}&3-3e^{-4t}&3-3e^{-4t}\\
3-4e^{-t}+e^{-4t}&3-3e^{-4t}&3+2e^{-t}+6e^{-3t}+e^{-4t}&3+2e^{-t}-6e^{-3t}+e^{-4t}\\
3-4e^{-t}+e^{-4t}&3-3e^{-4t}&3+2e^{-t}-6e^{-3t}+e^{-4t}&3+2e^{-t}+6e^{-3t}+e^{-4t}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Which they have then broken apart into the matrices of coefficients of the exponential expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much!